# Using old roaming profiles after Domain controller change

Tags: domain-controller, roaming-profile

Is it possible to keep the current network profiles on users' machines even if the domain changes?

It is not necessary to migrate current users from the old server, but the local network profiles should be preserved, because otherwise it causes additional work, for example when all users' Outlook profiles have to be redone.

Does this method still work on Windows 11 machines?
https://serverfault.com/a/143995/113487

Comment: If you’re not migrating users, then all the users are technically different users. You’re going to have problems with permissions in the roaming folders. They are probably owned by a user that is no longer going to exist. You’re going to have to fix all of that. There may be other problems embedded in the roaming profile itself due to the SID change. It’s definitely going to conflict with any local data already on the workstation. Simply put I do not think your idea of recreating new users and keeping their old roaming profiles is a good one. Why do you need a “new” domain?

Comment: Because i have to recreate all Outlook-profiles (with x amount of email accounts) to users.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate new users or a new domain? Why are you not able to upgrade or migrate your existing domain and users? You are effectively starting fresh, so you might as well go all the way with new profiles. Otherwise just keep the existing domain. Plus, outlook can configure itself through automated mechanisms or scripting. That is not a reason to  risk the issues you might have trying to do this. You’ll be better off in the long run either biting the bullet and starting fresh, or keeping the existing domain and users through upgrades/migrations. But, by all means give it a shot.